# Squares splitting into 4 congruent shapes

Tags: mathematics, geometry

how many ways can you divide a square into four congruent shapes? Remember that the answer cannot be infinity because rotations of one pattern still result in the same four congruent shapes.

Comment: Huh? It should definitely be infinite. Draw two perpendicular lines which intersect at the center, and it will always partition the square into four congruent parts, no???

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [greenturtle3141's comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52526/squares-splitting-into-4-congruent-shapes#comment160941_52526), there are indeed

> infinite

ways to split the square into 4 congruent shapes without rotations.

> Draw two lines crossing through the square's center, splitting it into 4 congruent shapes. If you were to pivot the lines around the square's center by any angle between 0 and 90 degrees (not inclusive), you end up with a new unique set of 4 congruent shapes. The range of unique rotations is *just* under 90 degrees; pivoting at least 90 degrees will result in a repeated split.
>  [image] 
>  [image]
>  The answer is "infinity" because the rotation angle can be infinitesimally small. Pivoting by just a tiny fraction of a degree will produce new shapes that are not rotations. The range of rotation (just under 90 degrees) is continuous, so there are infinite possible angles.
>  It is possible that there are other ways to draw these two lines to divide the square into 4 congruent shapes. However, it doesn't matter, because infinity plus any positive number is still infinity.